# HTML anchor tag not working to download file in android platform

Tags: javascript, android, html, visual-studio-2013, download

First, I'm trying to developing a mobile application by using Visual Studio 2013 to download a file from local server.

I use this code to download a file. It works fine when click on pages, but not responding when I trying to download file on android. (Cannot put target download path for Android in anchor tag)

Is there any way to download a file using HTML (anchor tag), or JavaScript?

Code:

```html
<a id='download' href='path_to_file' download><img class='thumb' src="url" /></a>
```

Comment: post your code pls^^

Comment: Do you use WebView or just TextView ?

Comment: @yummy I not sure, but u mentioned I consider not using and I write the code on html and build on android.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more control with JavaScript. This snippet creates an "invisible" anchor element and clicks it. Running the snippet will download a picture of a goat.

```js
var myURL = 'http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg'
handleAndroidMobile(myURL);

function handleAndroidMobile(myURL) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'Downloaded_file_name';
  link.href = myURL;
  link.click();
}
```

I'm not sure how to specify a path. If I find a solution I'll update this answer.